How to connect spark to kafka on docker
i can not connect spark to kafka even though i made a image from binami/spark and add library spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.3.jar and kafka-clients-3.5.2 and image's name is "spark-kafka-2". This is file docker-compose.yml:
my error is can not connect spark to kafka and its:
An error occurred: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide


x-common-env: &common-env
  KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
  KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER: PLAINTEXT, INTERNAL: PLAINTEXT, EXTERNAL: PLAINTEXT' 
  KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL 
  KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker1:29093,2@broker2:29093'  
  KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker, controller'
  KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
  KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
  CLUSTER_ID: 'cing71WazngRchaPES6qSA=='
  KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /tmp/kraft-combined-logs  
  KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
  CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
  CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: anonymous

x-common-healthcheck: &common-healthcheck  
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 5

services:
  broker1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server
    container_name: broker1
    hostname: broker1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      <<: *common-env
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://broker1:29092,CONTROLLER://broker1:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://broker1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092'
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker1:29092
    healthcheck:
      <<: *common-healthcheck
      test: ["CMD", "bash", "-c", "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 9092"]
    networks:
      - datamasterylab  

  broker2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server
    container_name: broker2
    hostname: broker2
    ports:
      - "9093:9093" 
    environment:
      <<: *common-env
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 2
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://broker2:29092,CONTROLLER://broker2:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://broker2:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093'
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker2:29092
    healthcheck:
      <<: *common-healthcheck
      test: ["CMD", "bash", "-c", "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 9093"]
    networks:
      - datamasterylab  
  
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center  
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center 
    ports:
      - "9021:9021" 
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker1:29092,broker2:29092
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021 
    networks:
      - datamasterylab  
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9021/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  
  minio:
    image: minio/minio 
    hostname: minio 
    container_name: minio 
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin 
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    networks:
      - datamasterylab

  mc-init:
    image: 'minio/mc'
    container_name: mc-init 
    entrypoint: |
      /bin/bash -c "
      sleep 5;
      /usr/bin/mc config --quiet host add dmlminio http://minio:9000 minioadmin minioadmin;
      /usr/bin/mc mb --quiet dmlminio/bronze;
      /usr/bin/mc admin service restart dmlminio;
      "
    depends_on:
      - minio 
    networks:
      - datamasterylab

  spark-master:
    image: spark-kafka-2
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    volumes:
      - ./jobs:/opt/bitnami/spark/jobs
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      SPARK_JAVA_OPTS: "-Dspark.sql.streaming.kafka.bootstrap.servers=broker1:29092,broker2:29092"
      SPARK_CLASSPATH: "/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/*"
    networks:
      - datamasterylab

  spark-worker:
    image: spark-kafka-2

    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    volumes:
      - ./jobs:/opt/bitnami/spark/jobs
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
      SPARK_JAVA_OPTS: "-Dspark.sql.streaming.kafka.bootstrap.servers=broker1:29092,broker2:29092"
      SPARK_CLASSPATH: "/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/*"
    networks:
      - datamasterylab

  

networks:
  datamasterylab:

i have a scripts python so connect spark to kafka.This is sourse code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, FloatType, DateType


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("streaming-kafka") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")

try:
   
    data = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker1:29092,broker2:29092") \
        .option("subscribe", "topic-india-2") \
        .load()
        
    
    schema_df = StructType([
        StructField("Airline_Name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Rating - 10", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("Title", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Date", DateType(), True),
        StructField("Review", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Recommond", StringType(), True)
    ])

   
    df = data.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as json_values") \
        .select(from_json(col("json_values"), schema_df).alias("data")) \
        .select("data.*")
    
   
    query = df.writeStream \
        .outputMode("complete") \
        .format("console") \
        .start()
        
    query.awaitTermination()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

and certainly i have topic in kafka and those broker are running.

See working code at https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb
